# Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-admin

I am getting following error while building my project while I haven't used firebase auth in my project:

> Error: Program type already present: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException

I have tried following but nothing seems to work

1. Use navigation option
2. clean rebuild
3. invalid cache
4. exclude group module

my dependencies are as:

```
dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(  dir: 'libs',include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
 implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-       core:3.0.2'
 implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.0'){
    exclude module:'com.google.firebase-auth'
 }
  }

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Firebase Admin SDK in an Android app. It can only be used in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.

If you remove this dependency, the error should disappear:

```
implementation ('com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.0'){
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually come from a naming conflict (Most probably because a class appears more than once in your project either in the form of dependencies or a mistake).

To find the list of dependencies for the module 'x' we can run
`./gradlew x:dependencies` to retrieve a list of all the libraries.

From the dependency tree, you an figure out if there is a class/library with the same name being used by two libraries. Based on this finding, you can choose to exclude the module in one of the libraries that are causing the conflict.